# C++ Tic Tac Toe Program Optimization

Tags: c++, optimization

I am pretty new to C++.

I just finished my first "real" Program.

It's a Tic Tac Toe game.

Is anybody willing to read trough my code an tell me where I could optimize something?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    /**< Board variables */
    string a1 = "_";    string a2 = "_";    string a3 = "_";
    string b1 = "_";    string b2 = "_";    string b3 = "_";
    string c1 = "_";    string c2 = "_";    string c3 = "_";

    string showboard (){
        cout << '\t' << ""<< '\t' << "1" << '\t' << "2" << '\t' << "3" << "\n";
        cout << '\t' << "a"<< '\t' << a1 << '\t' << a2 << '\t' << a3 << "\n";
        cout << '\t' << "b"<< '\t' << b1 << '\t' << b2 << '\t' << b3 << "\n";
        cout << '\t' << "c"<< '\t' << c1 << '\t' << c2 << '\t' << c3 << "\n\n";
        return "";
    };

    /**< Turn */
    int turn;
    /**< useless variable */
    int x =1;
    /**< "tiles" for example "X" or "O" */
    string boardvalue;

    /**< Checks if Turn is valid/legal */
    string turnvalidation (string boardvalue){
            if(turn==1 && a1!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==2 && a2!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==3 && a3!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==4 && b1!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==5 && b2!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==6 && b3!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==7 && c1!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==8 && c2!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==9 && c3!="_"){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else if(turn==10){
                cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
                x=1;
            } else {

                x=0;
                switch (turn){

                    case 1: a1=boardvalue; break;
                    case 2: a2=boardvalue; break;
                    case 3: a3=boardvalue; break;
                    case 4: b1=boardvalue; break;
                    case 5: b2=boardvalue; break;
                    case 6: b3=boardvalue; break;
                    case 7: c1=boardvalue; break;
                    case 8: c2=boardvalue; break;
                    case 9: c3=boardvalue; break;
                }
            }
            return"";
    };

    /**< Checks if the game is won */
    int wincheck(string boardvalue){
    // Rows
    if(a1==boardvalue && a2==boardvalue && a3==boardvalue){return 0;}else
    if(b1==boardvalue && b2==boardvalue && b3==boardvalue){return 0;}else
    if(c1==boardvalue && c2==boardvalue && c3==boardvalue){return 0;}else

    // Columns
    if(a1==boardvalue && b1==boardvalue && c1==boardvalue){return 0;}else
    if(a2==boardvalue && b2==boardvalue && c2==boardvalue){return 0;}else
    if(a3==boardvalue && b3==boardvalue && c3==boardvalue){return 0;}else

    // Diagonals
    if(c1==boardvalue && b2==boardvalue && a3==boardvalue){return 0;}else
    if(a1==boardvalue && b2==boardvalue && c3==boardvalue){return 0;}else
    {return 1;};
    }

int main()
{
    string player1;
    string player2;

    cout << "Player 1 enter your name \n";
    cin >> player1;

    cout << "\nPlayer 2 enter your name \n";
    cin >> player2;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Input example: a1 [enter]\n\n";

    string turni; /**< Converts Input in switch value! */

    while(1){ /**< Play again */
            string a1 = "_";    string a2 = "_";    string a3 = "_";
            string b1 = "_";    string b2 = "_";    string b3 = "_";
            string c1 = "_";    string c2 = "_";    string c3 = "_";
        while(1){

            /**< Player 1s turn */
            x=1;
            while(1){

                cout << player1 << " place your X \n\n";
                showboard();
                cin >> turni;

                if(turni=="a1"){turn=1;} else if(turni=="a2"){turn=2;} else if(turni=="a3"){turn=3;} else if(turni=="b1"){turn=4;} else if(turni=="b2"){turn=5;} else if(turni=="b3"){turn=6;} else if(turni=="c1"){turn=7;} else if(turni=="c2"){turn=8;} else if(turni=="c3"){turn=9;} else{turn=10;};

                /**< Checks if Turn is valid/legal */

                turnvalidation("X");
                break;
            }

            /**< Win Check */

            if(wincheck("X") == 0){

                showboard();
                cout << "Congratulations " << player1 << " you won!";
                break;
            };

            /**< Player 1s turn is over */


            /**< Player 2s turn */
            x=1;
            while(1){

                cout << player2 << " place your 0 \n\n";
                showboard();
                cin >> turni;

                if(turni=="a1"){turn=1;} else if(turni=="a2"){turn=2;} else if(turni=="a3"){turn=3;} else if(turni=="b1"){turn=4;} else if(turni=="b2"){turn=5;} else if(turni=="b3"){turn=6;} else if(turni=="c1"){turn=7;} else if(turni=="c2"){turn=8;} else if(turni=="c3"){turn=9;} else{turn=10;};

                /**< Checks if Turn is valid/legal */

                turnvalidation("O");
                break;
            }

            /**< Win Check */

            if(wincheck("O")==0){

                showboard();
                cout << "Congratulations " << player2 << " you won!";
                break;
            };

            /**< Player 1s turn is over */
        }

            /**< Play again and clear board */
        cout << "\n\nIf you want to play again type ""1""! \n";
        cin >> x;

        if(x==1){
        a1 = "_";     a2 = "_";     a3 = "_";
        b1 = "_";     b2 = "_";     b3 = "_";
        c1 = "_";     c2 = "_";     c3 = "_";
        } else {break;}
    }
}
```

The game itself works.

but

In this section is an error:

```
        cout << "\n\nIf you want to play again type ""1""! \n";
        cin >> x;

        if(x==1){
        a1 = "_";     a2 = "_";     a3 = "_";
        b1 = "_";     b2 = "_";     b3 = "_";
        c1 = "_";     c2 = "_";     c3 = "_";
        } else {break;}
```

You get to this section by winning.

If you type "1" the game will restart and should clear the board.

Every other input will close the program.

The game will restart but the board won't clear.

Comment: If your code works and you're just looking for peer review, you should post on [codereview.se] instead. This site is for questions about problems you're having, not *Can you take a look at this for me?* questions.

Comment: You declared 9 variables rather than some kind of array or structure and that forces your code to have lots of duplication all through it. When your code starts to look like it's pieces have all been copied/pasted, that's an indication that you've done something wrong.

Comment: You're lucky tic-tac-toe only has 9 positions.  Learn to use arrays.

Comment: "You get to this section by winning." Pah. Study the classics. ["The only winning move is not to play."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)

Answer (score 1):

**Your mistake is here**

```
while(1){ /**< Play again */
            string a1 = "_";    string a2 = "_";    string a3 = "_";
            string b1 = "_";    string b2 = "_";    string b3 = "_";
            string c1 = "_";    string c2 = "_";    string c3 = "_";
```

You should not declare them again when you already declared them as global.

You should change this part to this. So your variables values will be updated everywhere.

```
while (1){ /**< Play again */
         a1 = "_";    a2 = "_";     a3 = "_";
         b1 = "_";    b2 = "_";     b3 = "_";
         c1 = "_";     c2 = "_";    c3 = "_";
```

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad Tayyab's answer is correct for fixing the bug. Give him the win, but an upvote would be nice if the below is also helpful. You're setting the board at start of game, you don't need to set it at any other time. Change the original statements to:

```
/* Board variables */
string a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3;
```

And the play again code to:

```
/**< Play again and clear board */
cout << "\n\nIf you want to play again type ""1""! \n";
cin >> x;

if (x != 1) 
{ 
    break; 
}
```

Additionally, you'd be better of using a vector/array for your board e.g. in a simple program get rid of a1 - c3 altogether and use:

```
int board[9]; // a1 now = board[0], a2 now = board[1] and so on
```

You can heavily simplify the "turnvalidation" function now.

Also you're repeating this code in both players's code:

```
if (turni == "a1") { turn = 1; }
else if (turni == "a2") { turn = 2; }
else if (turni == "a3") { turn = 3; }
else if (turni == "b1") { turn = 4; }
else if (turni == "b2") { turn = 5; }
else if (turni == "b3") { turn = 6; }
else if (turni == "c1") { turn = 7; }
else if (turni == "c2") { turn = 8; }
else if (turni == "c3") { turn = 9; }
else { turn = 10; };
```

With a board[9] array instead and combining that code into the validation function (also change the name to "movevalidation") you can do this:

```
bool movevalidation(string move_string, string player_symbol)
{
    string moves[9] = { "a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3" };
    int move_int = -1; // -1 means invalid
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        if (move_string == moves[i])
            move_int = i;
    }

    if (moves < 0 || board[move_int] != "_")
    {
        cout << "Invalid option. Choose again! \n\n";
        return false;
    }

    board[move_int] = player_symbol;
    return true;
}
```

And the player-select-move loop turns into this:

```
        while (1) {

            cout << player1 << " place your X \n\n";
            showboard();
            cin >> turni;

            if(movevalidation(turni)) 
                break;
        }
```

For both players. With an array you also need to change the clear-board code to be a loop:

```
while (1) { /**< Play again */
    for(int i = 0; i < 9 ++i)
        board[i] = "_";
```

you have to change your wincheck to account for the replacement of the name with the array names. You can simply replace a1 with board[0], a2 with board[1] and so on.

Comment: Dude that's incredible. Thanks a lot for the detailed describtion. I teach myself  c++ with a book and heaven learned about arrays yet so I used the tools I knew of. If I'll ever get to 15 reputation you will see my upvote.